# How can I change the vertical position of content after a tabularnewline?

Tags: latex

I have some trouble with tables in LaTeX. My table has 4 columns. The are too broad to fit the \textwidth, so I searched for a line break and found \tabularnewline. Now the content in the first column breaks into 2 lines but the content in the other 3 columns is now at the bottom of the cell. I would like to center it in the column, or at least it should be at the ceiling. How can I do that?

I tried tabular, tabular* and tabularx. I would like to write as little commands as possible. Is there maybe a way to do it similarly easily as in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\usepackage{array} in your preamble

then you can use \begin{tabular}{c c m} -- the 'm' will give you vertical middle alignment.
also: 't' will give you top alignment, and 'b' will give you bottom.

Comment: \begin{tabular}{c c m} does not work. Do I have to specify a width for "m"?

Answer (score 0):

Not as easy as I hoped it would be but \multirow does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the paragraph format specifier for one or more of the columns?

That is `p{<length>}` as in:

```
\begin{tabular}{|rrp{4.5cm}l|}
  ...
```

Multirow seems like overkill for most of the use cases I am envisioning.

NB: The "length" can be computed from other values as is `0.4\textwidth`, but is always a constant. Don't know off hand how rubber reacts in this case.

Comment: I tried that, but all examples I found use fixed values which I find unfunctional. Also the cell content wasn't in the vertical center.

Comment: Ah, well. Fixed values are the part and parcel of the `p` specifier, which is why I avoid them when possible. I think you can use the usual formatting commands to adjust how things layout inside the each cell.